# Your question does not meet quality standards

Tags: discussion

How does the software make this decision?  I find it frustrating to try to help (I wrote a post about merging two tags) and then have my attempt blocked.

Maybe none of you have seen this message:

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, now that this slipped through the blocking net: graph-algorithm and graph-algorithms are both tags, and should be merged.

Comment: I guess the most common reason for getting this error message is posting a question that is too short.

Comment: I'll create a synonym....done.

Comment: I know that is frustrating….  [The exact criteria are secret](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) for a reason I do not understand.  You can see that [many people on Meta Stack Overflow are confused by that message](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22It+does+not+meet+our+quality+standards%22), if it eases your frustration (but probably it does not).

Comment: Thanks, Tsuyoshi, that clarifies the situation.  Clearly their software does not contemplate reporting a trivial tag-merge issue in meta!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think shortness is the main criterion

Comment: I don't think it is that straightforward, but I'm not inclined to pursue this further. Next time I will pad. :-)

Comment: It's possibly also a lack of links or other 'nontrivial words'. These are things that are different from MO because we have no control over it.